# How to run "conda ***" in a system command in R

Tags: r, bash, conda

I want to run a system command in a conda environment, but I can't figure out how to get R to send the command to a properly initialized bash shell. I tried `system('conda activate myenv && mycommand')`, but I get a warning about needing to run `conda init bash`. Trying `system('conda init bash && conda activate myenv')` throws the same error. Making `bash` the first command freezes RStudio, e.g. `system('bash && ....`)`.

Is there any way to send a system command in R that would run AFTER sourcing my .bashrc file?

Answer (score 3):

Use Conda Run.

```r
system('conda run -n myenv mycommand')
```

See `conda run --help` for details.

Comment: You'd still have to source `conda.sh` prior to this, right?

Comment: @Dunois no, that sets up `conda activate`, which is really only needed for interactive shell sessions. The only prerequisite here is the system being able to resolve the `conda` entrypoint (e.g., the `miniconda3/condabin` is on PATH).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `system('source ~/.bashrc && conda activate myenv && mycommand')` after running `conda init` and your `.bashrc` file contains a block of code delimited by:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
...
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```